# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeAppearance.NativeAppearance.initialPreferences')

Tags: react-native

i have upgraded my project to ExpoSDK 46. On the web everything works well, but when trying to run the project on iOS or Android using the ExpoGo App, i’m getting the following error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeAppearance.NativeAppearance.initialPreferences')
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:null in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:null in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: have the same isue, if already solved it please help. Thank you